# How do I pass options in to a Handler in Leaflet JS?

Tags: leaflet

Using leaflet 1.0.2, I have been following the tutorial [Extending Leaflet: Handlers and Controls](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html) and I am building my own handler to draw a "bounding box" on the map.

So far this works very well, see the following example "pseudo" code:

```
L.BoundingBoxHandler = L.Handler.extend({
  colour: '#0000FF',
  rectangle: null,
  addHooks: function () {
    L.DomEvent.on(this._map._container, 'mousedown', this.start, this);
    L.DomEvent.on(this._map._container, 'mousemove', this.mouseMove, this);
    L.DomEvent.on(this._map._container, 'mouseup', this.mouseUp, this);
  },

  removeHooks: function () {
    L.DomEvent.off(this._map._container, 'mousedown', this.start, this);
    L.DomEvent.off(this._map._container, 'mousemove', this.mouseMove, this);
    L.DomEvent.off(this._map._container, 'mouseup', this.mouseUp, this);
  },

  start: function (ev: MouseEvent) {
    // get the lat long bounds of the mouse then draw a rectangle
    this.rectangle = L.rectangle(latLngBounds, { color: this.colour, 
    weight: 2 }).addTo(this._map);
  },

  mouseMove: function (ev: MouseEvent) {
    // code that gets the current location of mouse 
    // and calls setBounds on the rectangle...
  },

  mouseUp: function (ev: MouseEvent) {
     // remove the bounding box
     this.rectangle.remove();
   }
 });
```

I am adding the handler to the map by calling:

```
map.addHandler('boundy', L.BoundingBoxHandler);
```

In the code example, you can see that I have a variable called "colour" which determines the colour of the rectangle.

I would like to pass this colour in as an option **when I create the handler**, so that I can change the colour of the rectangle.

How do I pass in options when I create the handler in Leaflet JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I pass in options when I create the handler in Leaflet JS?

You don't.

Look at how the default map handlers work: the use the **map options** to define their own behaviour.

For example, the [code for the `ScrollWheelZoom` handler](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/handler/Map.ScrollWheelZoom.js) defines the following options in the map:

- An *implicit* `scrollWheelZoom` option for enabling/disabling the handler when the map is instantiated.
- `wheelDebounceTime` and `wheelPxPerZoomLevel` options for the behaviour of the handler.

It is perfectly OK for a handler to define new map options, as long as the names don't collide with the existing ones.

So if you've got a `BoundingBox` handler, you probably want to have an implicit `boundingBox` option and something like a `boundingBoxStyle` option, both as map options.